# Where can I find a list of Thunderbird CSS classes/IDs to manipulate the folder pane

Tags: thunderbird, css

Where can I find a list of Thunderbird CSS classes/IDs to manipulate the folder pane

I would like to manipulate the colors (and maybe sizes) of some of the CSS in the folder pane. The the key item I am interested in is changing the blue color (to red) for the "new mail" indication, which currently seems to be #00f.

I know that once I have the list I need, I would place my changes in userChrome.css.

Any help appreciated.

[image: Thunderbird folder pane]

Answer (score 0):

The general location in the source code for CSS of the UI can be found in this path:

`/comm-central/mail/themes/shared/mail`

And for javascript and xhtml:

`/comm-central/mail/base/content`

Be warned, the [guidance for obtaining the source code locally](https://developer.thunderbird.net/thunderbird-development/getting-started) will entail substantial download times and eat up considerable disk space ("The source code requires 3.6GB of free space or more and additionally 5GB or more for default build."):

```
hg clone https://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central source/
cd source/
hg clone https://hg.mozilla.org/comm-central comm/
```

One can also view the source code online here:

https://searchfox.org/comm-central/source/

---

Apart from pouring over source code, one can also enable the `Tools > Developer Tools > Developer Toolbox (Ctrl+Shift+I)` to get access to the element picker tool, which will let you mouse over elements of the UI and then see all of the pertinent details, including CSS classes/IDs, as well as copy CSS selectors. Starting the Developer Toolbox will trigger an "Incoming Connection" dialog with Client and Server endpoints that one will need to allow (click "Ok") before the developer tools show up.

All this being said, the use of `userChrome.css` is not officially supported, and hacking away at the internals of the UI like this is likely to be a significant maintenance burden for anyone that undertakes the effort, especially once Thunderbird adopts a monthly release cadence.